# How to disable google maps autocompletion

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, twitter-typeahead

I have one text field and I am using two different autocompletion methods depending on selected radion button(first option: google maps api, second option: twitter-typeahead). My question is how to disable google maps autocompletion?

```
$('#search_type_name').click(function(){
    google.maps.event.clearInstanceListeners(geoAutocomplete);
    $("#local").typeahead(null, {
        displayKey: 'name',
        source: numbers.ttAdapter()
    });
});

$('#search_type_address').click(function(){
    $("#local").typeahead('destroy');
    $("#local").off();

    geoAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        (document.getElementById('local')),
        {types: ['geocode']}
    );
    geoAutocomplete.addListener('place_changed');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must also remove the listeners bound to the `<input>`

```
google.maps.event.clearInstanceListeners($("#local")[0]);
```

Currently  you only remove the listeners of the Autocomplete-instance(`place_changed`), but not the listeners that have been added by the Maps-API(key-events, focus, blur etc.)